# Cmake linker error with shared libraries

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

Im having an error on a chain linking, I've read lots of post but can't find a solution.

I build 3 libraries, in separated folders:

lib_1 as shared without dependencies

lib_2 as shared requiring lib_1 (build without problems)

lib_3 as shared that requires both lib_1 & lib_2

Here are the simplified CMakelists.txt (path have been simplified & triple-checked and mines are ok)

```
project (lib_1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include_directories( lib_1/include/path/)
add_library(lib_1 SHARED lib_1/source/path)
```

====================================

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (lib_2)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include_directories( lib_2/include/path/)
add_library(lib_2 SHARED lib_2/source/path)

add_library(lib_1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_1 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "lib_1/path/file.dylib")
```

=============

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (lib_3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)


include_directories( lib_3/include/path/)

add_library(lib_3 SHARED lib_3/sources/path)


add_library(lib_1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_1 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/lib_1/path/file.dylib")

add_library(lib_2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_2 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/lib_2/path/file.dylib")
```

Funny thing is I think that add_library & set_property of lib_3 do nothing as removing the line doesn't change the error, i.e. I'm not doing what I should...but I've no idea anymore.

(Side note code runs smoothly if I build all files at once, but I'm trying my hands at shared libraries)

Error for reference:

> [100%] Linking CXX shared library lib_3.dylib
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "LIB_1 function", referenced from:
>          in lib_3.cpp.o
>   [...]

Followed by all lib_1 & lib_2 functions marker as undefined

Comment: You forget to **link libraries** with `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've no words......; still why did lib_2 build? its not building lib_1 sources, but could still link

Comment: OK understood, I actually had the call to lib_1 commented, well, that was simple thank you